# How to fix low quality gray-scale printing on HP Color LaserJet CP4525?

Tags: printing, hp

When I print in grey-scale, gray text and grey areas are printed with small black dots instead of using real gray. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Select the **hpijs** driver `HP Color LaserJet cp4520 Series hpijs pcl3, 3.18.7` instead of the hpcups driver which is shown as recommended.